# facebook permission issue when i use app from my website?

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0, facebook-oauth, facebook-authorization

i have developed a facebook app. which requires a extended permission .
Evertything works fine when i access application from

```
http://apps.facebook.com/test-samplefb-app/
```

its ask for all permission including extended permission and work as the way i want.

but when i try access application from my site it only ask for basic permission not for extra and extended permission . becouse of which i am able to get only not other 'installed permission' .

Note : i am using oauth.

can anyone help why this is happening ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you providing the list of permissions when you trying access application of your site. Because in case you are getting desired list of permission then probably you are not specifying the needed permission and it is asking for default ones.

Comment: no i am not specifying the permission . i am using Auth Dialog of facebook .

Comment: Why don't you specify the permissions to your auth dialog. It should solve the problem.

Comment: solved : it works when i append auth_referral = 1 in login url :)

Answer (score 0):

solved : it works when i append auth_referral = 1 in login url :)